# How can I convert Sha-512 hash in Java to its Node.js equivalent

Tags: java, node.js, cryptojs

I have a simple hashing function in Java that I rewrote in Node.js but they produce different result.

Here is the Java:

```
public static String get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(String str, String customerId) {
    try {
        MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        instance.update(customerId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] digest = instance.digest(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : digest) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((b & 255) + 256, 16).substring(1));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is the Node.js equivalent I produced.

```
let crypto = require('crypto');

function get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(str, customerId) {
    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512')
    hash.update(customerId, 'utf8')
    let value = hash.digest(str, 'uft8')
    console.log(value.toString('hex'))
    return value.toString('hex');
}
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong or why they are different if I reproduced right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very nearly there, the issue is that the [.digest](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding) function does not take an argument in Node.js, so we'll call [.update](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding) twice, once with customerId, then with str. We don't actually need to pass the string encoding to the .update function since utf8 is the default encoding.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(str, customerId) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
    const digest = hash.update(customerId, "utf-8").update(str, "utf-8").digest();
    return digest.toString("hex");
}

console.log(get_SHA_512_SecurePassword("hello", "world"));
```

This  Node.js example outputs:

```
3e64afa1cb7d643aa36f63b8d092ad76b1f04ff557abbb3d05f5b9037abf68a6606a8885d51bec8f6f39ee7d0badd504241c3704e777a51c21a9723e285fb9b8
```

Which should be the same output as the Java code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you use the crypto wrong in node.js. The digest() method in java is a little different than in crypto in node.js

Java [MessageDigest Api Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)

> digest(byte[] input) Performs a final update on the digest using the
> specified array of bytes, then completes the digest computation.

So in java you provide another string in digest and consumes it to produce a new hash and then produces the output

In node.js however the documentation for `hmac.digest()` states [Crypto Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_digest_encoding)

```
hmac.digest([encoding])
```

> Calculates the HMAC digest of all of the data passed using
> hmac.update(). If encoding is provided a string is returned; otherwise
> a Buffer is returned;

So it will not accept another string to be encoded like you pass `str` in that function. It will accept only an encoding.

So in your code

```
function get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(str, customerId) {
    let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512')
    hash.update(customerId, 'utf8')
    let value = hash.digest(str, 'uft8') <-----this is wrong
    console.log(value.toString('hex'))
    return value.toString('hex');
}
```

The following would be the right one

```
  function get_SHA_512_SecurePassword(str, customerId) {
        let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512')

        hash.update(customerId, 'utf8')
        hash.update(str, 'utf8')
        let value = hash.digest('hex')

        console.log(value)
        return value;
    }
```